# Руби ошибка SSL сертификата

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ruby, ssl

при попытке подключится к сайту по апи, выкидывает

```
933:in `connect_nonblock': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

небезопасное соединение установить нет возможности, версия руби 2.3.1, ubuntu 16.04, подскажите как решить. Спасибо

Comment: *certificate verify failed* — перевод: *сертификат проверить не удалось*

Comment: спасибо, я бы без вашей помощи не смог перевести

Comment: Приведите кусок кода, в котором отправляется запрос к АПИ

Comment: https://github.com/funzoneq/dnsmadeeasy-rest-api/blob/master/lib/dnsmadeeasy-rest-api.rb#L11

Comment: А с настройкой времени всё в порядке на машине, откуда шлется запрос?

Comment: А пакет `ca-certificates` установлен?

Comment: пакет ca-certificates установлен и обновлен, время выставлено правильно, через браузер по аштитипиэс подключается

Comment: попробовал версию 2.2.3 , ошибка та же...очень нужна помощь

Comment: У этого может быть довольно много причин, хотя корень у всех один: Ruby не верит сертификату сервера. [Ознакомьтесь](http://mislav.net/2013/07/ruby-openssl/).

Comment: @D-side , воспользовался этим скриптом - https://github.com/mislav/ssl-tools/blob/8b3dec4/doctor.rb , вот что выдало в консоле: 

     `OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016: /usr/lib/ssl
SSL_CERT_DIR=""
SSL_CERT_FILE="/usr/local/etc/cacert.pem"

HEAD https://status.github.com:443
#<Net::HTTPGatewayTimeOut 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT readbody=true>`

Comment: Ну, это уже не `SSLError`.

Comment: @D-side это выдало тем скриптом, а моя проблема так и осталась, с таким же выводом, можешь пожалуйста подсказать что можно сделать,в выводе он не указывает директорию сертификата, хотя линукс выводит ее путь, SSL_CERT_DIR="" . Может это как то в руби можно настроить, или проблема совсем не в этом

Comment: Этот скрипт должен был выдать совсем не 504, https://status.github.com/ выдаёт вполне конкретную страничку со статусом 200. Если не смог даже он, проблемы в настройке где-то ещё глубже. Может, даже не в Ruby. Если найдёте папку с CA-хранилищем вашей машины, попробуйте указать её вручную.

Comment: @D-side терминал мне выдает echo $SSL_CERT_DIR , а вот этот скрипт ее уже не видит

Comment: Его префикс, по идее, должен быть в `OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_AREA`. Пробейте отладчиком, он там есть?

Comment: @D-side нету отладчика

Comment: `irb`-то есть хотя бы?

Comment: @D-side не устанавливал, создал просто файлик руби, и попросил вывести, результат nil

Comment: Если у вас есть Ruby, то скорее всего есть и `irb`. Они обычно ставятся одним пакетом.

Comment: я ставил только руби что бы отладить скрипт на работе, и тут же столкнулся с проблемой этого сертификата.. установил irb, что туда вписывать?